# Program to help speed read regular books

Tags: ios, reading

Are there any iOS applications that will accelerate reading of a regular book?

For example, you could place your iPad in front of your text book and then it would highlight or block out text so that you stay focused and read more quickly the material that's being presented.

Comment: Interesting! I understand the app could block the book's page numbers and other decoration, but how should the app choose what to highlight?

Comment: Algorithmicly it's pretty simple since it's mainly looking for whitespace and just attempting to parse based on that visually...

Comment: So you suggest it should highlight the whole text?

Comment: It would highlight the text in sequence, progressively.

Comment: I see! At a speed that you can configure?